# SQLAlchemy returns None for a query that returns a value in DB manager

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

im using SQLAlchemy with postgres, using the same user in SQLALchemy as in my database management tool (DBeaver)

the problem is that the same exact query returns none in SQLAlchemy and a value in DBeaver

SQLAlchemy query

```py
test = db.session.execute("SELECT * FROM my_view")
for row in test:
    print(row)
```

redacted result, repalced strings with '' and numbers with 1: `('', 1, '', 1, '', '', 1, '', datetime, 1, None)` <- last value is none!

DBeaver query
[image: SELECT * FROM my_view, shows a result]

as you can see the last column does show a result, although ive had to blur it

any help towards figuring out what goes wrong is appreciated

Comment: Have you checked if it works if you would use SQLAlchemy ORM?

Comment: @Nf4r that is what i was using originally, i then tried using the execute to try to understand whats happening

Comment: It's really hard to tell what is the problem. I would check first if the credentials are good. Then I would try maybe to insert something (either by pure SQL or ORM) and check if this appears in your db table.

Comment: @Nf4r thank you, but it seems i am simply a bit dumb, i never committed my changes so my database server didn't actually know them. i thought i had set DBeaver to autocommit but apparently i didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems im a bit dumb

i had thought DBeaver was set to autocommit, since it showed me something similar, but apparently it was not, and i didn't press commit because i assumed autocommit. The autocommit setting must have accidentally gotten changed, maybe i accidentally hit a shortcut, because i distinctly remember autocommit working earlier today.

this means, that i always thought the problem was on SQLAlchemys side, but it was actually me never committing the changes.

be sure to always commit.